# RxTextView text changes + retrofit call leads to InterruptedIOException

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

Many RxJava tutorials with `RxTextView.textChanges` examples and `debounce`, use 'live search'. For example: [Improving UX with RxJava](https://medium.com/@diolor/improving-ux-with-rxjava-4440a13b157f#.crkt0apil). So I've implemented this example and I tried to play around:

```
RxTextView.textChanges(searchView)
          .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .skip(1)
          .debounce(DELAY_BEFORE_REQUEST_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .map(new Func1<CharSequence, String>() {
                @Override public String call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    return charSequence.toString();
                }
            })
          .switchMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Response>>() {
                @Override public Observable<Response> call(String query) {
                    return retrofitService.search(query);
                }
            })
          .subscribe();
```

Everything looked good, until I decided to simulate **GPRS** network type on **Android emulator**.

First api call was triggered, and when I added next letter to '**searchView**', app crashed with `InterruptedIOException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
      at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:60)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
   Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: thread interrupted
      at rx.Observable$27.onError(Observable.java:7923)
      at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:159)
      at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onError(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:71)
      at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onError(SerializedObserver.java:159)
      at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:79)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSwitch$SwitchSubscriber.error(OperatorSwitch.java:223)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSwitch$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorSwitch.java:282)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:240)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:776)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:537)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:526)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:250)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onError(OperatorMap.java:48)
      at retrofit2.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:114)
      at retrofit2.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:88)
      at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
      at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
      at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
      at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
      at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSwitch$SwitchSubscriber.onNext(OperatorSwitch.java:105)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSwitch$SwitchSubscriber.onNext(OperatorSwitch.java:60)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onNext(OperatorDoOnEach.java:85)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
      at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:95)
      at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:95)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDebounceWithTime$DebounceState.emit(OperatorDebounceWithTime.java:132)
      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDebounceWithTime$1$1.call(OperatorDebounceWithTime.java:79)
      at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
   Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
      at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
      at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
      at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
      at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
      at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
      at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:184)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:125)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:723)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:81)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:708)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:563)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.ge
```

I have searched a little, and it looks like I'm not alone: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698333/robolectric-rxjava-retrofit-second-call-throws-java-io-interruptedioexceptio) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382018/interruptedioexception-while-using-retrofit2-with-rx-when-retryon).

Author of that first question solved this problem this by wrapping retrofit request with try-catch block.
For me it is attempt of covering bad architecture. And I'm looking for cleaner solution.

Is there a way of ignoring first API call result, and starting new one using RxJava? Or I should try to switch over new Retrofit Call API, and try to cancel previous request (and break a reactive approach)?

I have using Retrofit 2 beta 3, with newest Okio and OkHttp.

Comment: any progress here?

Comment: @alexeypolusov I have switched to implementation found on some blog. Look at https://lorentzos.com/improving-ux-with-rxjava-4440a13b157f for possible different solutions (do not remember if it was the correct one)

Answer (score 5):

Well, the error is pretty explicit, you should add `onError` handling. It could look something like this:

```
.subscribe(new Observer<Response>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Response response) {
    }
});
```

However, your subscription will be terminated once an error is emitted, but you can avoid this by handling the errors of the API call like this:

```
.switchMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Response>>() {
    @Override public Observable<Response> call(String query) {
        return retrofitService.search(query)
                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<Response>empty());
    }
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about error handling, I've cut it for presentation. Rather than swallow exceptions, I would like to prevent it.

Comment: I guess that you could use `flatMap` instead of `switchMap`, so the previous Observable won't be unsubscribed, and `InterruptedIOException` won't be thrown anymore. But you would still have the a similar issue when there would be a network fail, for instance. So you can't prevent all the exceptions, and using `onErrorResumeNext` looks pretty clean to me. At least, it's more cleaner than having a try-catch block.

Comment: FlatMap doesn't help here - same error. In normal code I have error handling. I know about network exceptions. This is unchecked exceptions vs checked exceptions. Some I would like to serve with onError (network), some of them need to be prevent from code (IOException).